# KG to lbs conversion not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, unit-conversion

I am new in JavaScript and can't figure out why is it not working.

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="weight_value" placeholder="Input Weight" />
                <select id="weight_unit">
                   <option value="lbs">KG to Pound</option>
                   <option value="kg">Pound to KG</option>
                </select>
                <button title="Convert" onclick="display_result()">Convert</button>
            <div id="result"></div>
<script src="hero.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
 function display_result(){

                        var kg = 0.45359237
                        var results = ""

                            if ($(this).val() == "kg") {
                                $("#result").val( $("#weight_value").val()*kg)
                            } else {
                                $("#result").val( $("#weight_value").val()/kg)
                            }
                        };
```

Comment: `val` is [used for input elements](http://api.jquery.com/val/). `$('#result')` is a `div`, not an input element. Use [`html` instead](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Comment: Thanks for the information @AndyTurner . It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
function display_result(){
    var kg = 0.45359237
    var results = ""
    if ($('#weight_unit').val() == "kg") {
        $("#result").html( $("#weight_value").val()*kg)
    } 
    else {
        $("#result").html( $("#weight_value").val()/kg)
    }
};
```

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: No problem. If the answer worked for you, feel free to mark it as correct =)